# NUMERIC_VALUE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER with flink while reading a csv

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading a csv file inside a flink job using

```
env.readCsvFile(input).ignoreFirstLine().pojoType(MyPojo.class,getFields());
```

The csv file consists of 30 fields and some of the fields may be empty.

For the above code I am continuously getting the exception :

```
ParserError NUMERIC_VALUE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER 
Expect field types: class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class 
java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class 
java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class 
java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class 
java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.String, class 
java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class 
java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class 
java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class 
java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer, class 
java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class 
java.lang.String 
in file: C:/tmp/sample
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.GenericCsvInputFormat.parseRecord(GenericCsvInputFormat.java:386)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.CsvInputFormat.readRecord(CsvInputFormat.java:115)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.DelimitedInputFormat.nextRecord(DelimitedInputFormat.java:527)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.CsvInputFormat.nextRecord(CsvInputFormat.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:167)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I am trying to read only a single with all the non-empty values the program succeeds. Can anyone help how to resolve the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says

> Numerical Value Illegal Character

which means that the one of the numerical (Integer) fields contains an illegal character, i.e., a character that the integer parser doesn't know how to handle.
So, the problem is with the data you are reading. I would try to identify the conflicting row and field.